# PHP/Javascript determinate if string matches a pattern/regex

Tags: php, regex, string, match

How to check if string like: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

match with pattern?

Example of string: 8659-CA3B-F2CD-ADFB-AFD4-0B7E-F5E4-DE59

String has always 8 block with 4 characters and 7 "-"

It s possible determinate it with php and javascript?

Thanks in any case.

Comment: did you try anything ? it seems straightforward to me.

Comment: Im not good with regex or similar =(

Comment: PHP or Javascript?

Comment: I need both, but php is solved =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it without regex, with array functions instead.

Explode to make an array of each group.
Use array map to count the string lenghts and use array_unique to remove duplicates.

```
$str = "8659-CA3B-F2CD-ADFB-AFD4-0B7E-F5E4-DE59";
$arr = explode("-", $str);
$len = array_unique(array_map("strlen", $arr));

If(count($arr) == 8 && count($len) == 1 && $len[0] == 4) {
    Echo "match";
}Else{
    Echo "no match";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/T7MG7